# hibernate enver findRevisions hashCode StackOverflowError

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

I tried to use enver as kotlin.

I just wanted to run the code below.

```
    @Transactional
    fun findOrderDraftHistory(id: Int, @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10, sort = ["rev#DESC"]) pageable: Pageable): Page<Revision<Int, OrderDraft>> {
        return orderDraftRepository.findRevisions(id, pageable)
    }
```

But I got an error.
I don't understand why.
Is there a solution?
Please let me know if you need anything.

The language uses kotlin.
The db language uses mysql.

create table

```
CREATE TABLE `order_draft` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_number` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `order_type` ENUM('OUTER','INNER') NOT NULL,
    `seller` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `seller_manager` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `seller_manager_phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sign1` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sign2` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `project_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `delivery_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `reference` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `total_price` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `approval_request` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `approval_request_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `approved` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0' ,
    `sign_off_on` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `signed_datetime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `returned` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `returned_reason` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `delivered` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `delivered_sign` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `delivered_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `termination` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0' ,
    `termination_sign` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `termination_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `used` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
    `creator` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `updator` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `order_draft_join_item` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `order_draft_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `item_code_full` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `item_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `standard_size` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `amount` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `unit_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `unit_price` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `supply_value` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `vat` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `total_price` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `remark` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `creator` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `updator` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

error log

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.myproject.test.model.User.hashCode(User.kt)
    at com.myproject.test.model.OrderDraft.hashCode(OrderDraft.kt)
    at com.myproject.test.model.OrderDraftJoinItem.hashCode(OrderDraftJoinItem.kt)
    at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:541)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.hashCode(CollectionProxy.java:131)
    at com.myproject.test.model.OrderDraft.hashCode(OrderDraft.kt)
    at com.myproject.test.model.OrderDraftJoinItem.hashCode(OrderDraftJoinItem.kt)
    at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:541)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.hashCode(CollectionProxy.java:131)
    at com.myproject.test.model.OrderDraft.hashCode(OrderDraft.kt)
    at com.myproject.test.model.OrderDraftJoinItem.hashCode(OrderDraftJoinItem.kt)
    at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:541)
2020-01-02 14:57:29.510 ERROR 21040 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] Exception Handler                        : kotlin.Unit
```

model code - order_draft

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited
import org.hibernate.envers.RelationTargetAuditMode
import java.io.Serializable
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*

enum class EOrderType (orderType: String) {
    INNER ("INNER"),
    OUTER ("OUTER")
}

@Audited
@Entity(name="order_draft")
data class OrderDraft(
    @Column(name = "order_number")
    val orderNumber: String,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "order_type")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
    val orderType: EOrderType,
    @Column
    var seller: String,
    @Column(name = "seller_manager")
    var sellerManager: String,
    @Column(name = "seller_manager_phone")
    var sellerManagerPhone: String,
    @Column(name = "project_name")
    var projectName: String,
    @Column(name = "delivery_date")
    var deliveryDate: String,
    @Column
    var reference: String,
    @Column(name = "total_price")
    var totalPrice: Int,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sign1")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    var sign1: User,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sign2")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
    var sign2: User,
    @Column(name = "approval_request")
    var approvalRequest: Boolean = false,
    @Column(name = "approval_request_date")
    var approvalRequestDate: LocalDateTime? = null,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sign_off_on")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
    var signOffOn: User? = null,
    @Column
    var approved: Boolean = false,
    @Column(name = "signed_datetime")
    var signedDatetime: LocalDateTime? = null,
    @Column
    var returned: Boolean = false,
    @Column(name="returned_reason")
    var returnedReason: String? = null,
    @Column
    var delivered: Boolean,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="delivered_sign")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
    var deliveredSign: User? = null,
    @Column(name="delivered_date")
    var deliveredDate: LocalDateTime? = null,
    @Column
    var termination: Boolean,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="termination_sign")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
    var terminationSign: User? = null,
    @Column(name="termination_date")
    var terminationDate: LocalDateTime? = null,
    @Column
    var used: Boolean = true,
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "order_draft_join_attachment")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    var attachment: List<Attachment>? = null,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderDraft")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    val orderDraftItem: MutableList<OrderDraftJoinItem>? = null
)
```

model code - orderDraftJoinItem

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited
import org.hibernate.envers.RelationTargetAuditMode
import org.springframework.data.annotation.ReadOnlyProperty
import java.io.Serializable
import javax.persistence.*

@Audited
@Entity(name="order_draft_join_item")
data class OrderDraftJoinItem (
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_draft_id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
    val orderDraft : OrderDraft,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="item_id")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    val item: Item,
    @Column(name="item_code_full")
    val itemCodeFull: String,
    @Column(name="item_name")
    val itemName: String,
    val standardSize: String,
    val amount: Int,
    @Column(name="unit_name")
    val unitName: String,
    @Column(name="unit_price")
    val unitPrice: Int,
    @Column(name="supply_value")
    val supplyValue: Int,
    val vat: Int,
    @Column(name="total_price")
    val totalPrice: Int,
    val remark: String,
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="order_draft_join_item_join_attachment")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    var attachment: List<Attachment>? = null
)
```

orderDraftRepository interface

```
interface OrderDraftRepository : JpaRepository<OrderDraft, Int>, OrderDraftRepositoryCustom, RevisionRepository<OrderDraft, Int, Int> {
}
```

Comment: case 1, After changing "data class" to "class" it has been solved

Comment: case 2. object move data class (){"here"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using data classes for your entities. Use regular classes.

The `hashCode()`, `equals()`and `toString()` of a data class uses all the properties declared in the constructor, and that of course causes stack overflows with cyclic references.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I love you!!
After changing "data class" to "class" it has been solved.

Comment: So, could you explain further about why "data class" using that property (declared in the constructor) causes cyclic references?

Comment: Or would you appreciate it if you could provide me with keywords that I can borrow wisdom from?

Comment: It doesn't *cause* a cyclic reference. Your entities already have cyclic references: an OrderDraft has many OrderDraftJoinItem, and an OrderDraftJoinItem has a reference to its OrderDraft. But data classes have automatically generated hashCode(), equals() and toString() methods, and these methods use all the properties declared in the primary constructor. So OrderDraft.hashCode() calls OrderDraftItem.hashCode(), which calls OrderDraft.hashCode(), whic calls OrderDraftItem.hashCode(), etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the easy and complete explanation!!